# Should I use WHERE NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN for getting the ids of relationship table?

Tags: mysql

I have `users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `uid` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `flname` varchar(60),
 PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And a relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE `relationship` (
 `rid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `from` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `to` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `from_2` (`from`,`to`),
 KEY `to` (`to`),
 CONSTRAINT `relationship_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `relationship_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`to`) REFERENCES `users` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to fetch those users that is not in a specific user's circle (Like G+). It means that user has not yet added those people to his/her circle. I tried the below query but it was empty:

```
SELECT uid FROM users WHERE flname LIKE'%john%' AND NOT EXISTS (Select `to` FROM relationship WHERE `from`=60)
```

The below query returns 3 records:

```
SELECT uid,flname FROM users WHERE flname LIKE'%john%'
```

Now users in the name of `john` who has been added by uid=60 should not have be shown! The result of this query is empty. I can't figure that out, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask what `karbar` contains?

Comment: It was a typo, sorry. It's now correct.

Comment: On the other hand, I think you missed a condition in your subquery specifying that `to` equals `users.uid`.

Comment: I don't think so! from=60 is the conditional that I need: `from=uid`

Comment: But you say here that you want all Johns while there are no relationships originating from user 60 (be it John or Paulette or whatever).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subquery should be correlated:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM users 
WHERE flname LIKE '%john%' 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *              --- doesn't matter what you put here for EXISTS subqueries
        FROM relationship 
        WHERE `from` = 60
          AND `to` = users.uid        --- this line added
     ) ;
```

---

(unrelated to the issue)

Whoever told you that it's a good idea to use reserved words like `to` and `from` as column or table names, deserves a kick.

---

You can have the same results with a `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or a `NOT IN` query:

```
SELECT uid 
FROM users 
WHERE flname LIKE '%john%' 
  AND uid NOT IN 
      ( SELECT `to` 
        FROM relationship 
        WHERE `from` = 60
     ) ;
```

Comment: Good point about reserved keys, I'll change them in my project.

Comment: What are the performance considerations here? Which one is better, and which one is worse in terms of performance? Is there a general rule, where you shouldn't use one or the other for such purpose.

Comment: @MichaelKruglos the question was about writing a query to get wanted results, not about performance. That would need an essay to write ;)

Comment: In short, I avoid `IN` and `NOT IN` subqueries in MySQL as (besides performance which is often not good) it's easy to get wrong results due to NULL values. `LEFT JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS` usually end up to having the same or similar execution plan so performance would be the same. I tend to prefer NOT EXISTS as queries are more readable for me, especially when there are many conditions / many NOT EXISTS subqueries / many LEFT JOIN - IS NULL checks.

Comment: Note however the "usually". It all depends on various other things like "is it one subquery or many", what version of MySQL, how big are the tables (main table and tables in the subquery), what indexes there are, what are the datatypes, etc.